# Separar subconjuntos de uma base em R

Tags: r

Estou com dificuldades de classificação de obter subconjuntos de uma determinada base de dados. Numa determinada linha ele possui a experessão que indica em qual etapa aqueles dados pertencem, por exemplo, a primeira linha tem a expressão `1.2. DADOS DOS ÓRGÃOS/ENTIDADES (ETAPA 1)` e preciso criar uma coluna chamada `ETAPA` que todos os dados abaixo dela fique escrito `Etapa 1` até a linha `2. BASES E REMUNERAÇÕES (ETAPA 2)` que a partir dai fica escrita `Etapa 2` na coluna. A base de dados segue abaixo. O excesso de `NA` é por conta de que a base original em excel possui várias colunas mescladas e cada etapa possui quantidade de colunas diferentes.

EDIT: a quantidade de linhas de cada Etapa é diferente, e abaixo é somente uma amostra da base original. Como uma análise dos dads de cada etapa será feita mensalmente gostaria de criar uma rotina para separar as bases de caa etapa!

```
    structure(list(X__1 = c("1.2. DADOS DOS ÓRGÃOS/ENTIDADES (ETAPA 1)", 
"CNPJ", "03.066.219/0001-81", "03.066.219/0001-81", "04.809.688/0001-06", 
"2. BASES E REMUNERAÇÕES (ETAPA 2)", "Competência", "Março", 
"Março", "Março", "Março", "3. CONTRIBUIÇÕES, APORTES E OUTROS VALORES (ETAPA 3)", 
"Competência", "Março", "Março", "Março", "Março"), X__2 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), X__3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), X__4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Órgão/Entidade", "AGENERSA - Agência Reguladora de Energia e Saneamento Básico do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
"AGENERSA - Agência Reguladora de Energia e Saneamento Básico do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
"AGETRANSP - Agência Reguladora de Serv.Público de Transportes do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
"AGETRANSP - Agência Reguladora de Serv.Público de Transportes do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
NA, "Órgão/Entidade", "AGENERSA - Agência Reguladora de Energia e Saneamento Básico do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
"AGENERSA - Agência Reguladora de Energia e Saneamento Básico do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
"AGETRANSP - Agência Reguladora de Serv.Público de Transportes do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
"AGETRANSP - Agência Reguladora de Serv.Público de Transportes do Estado do Rio de Janeiro"
), X__6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), X__7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    X__8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__9 = c(NA, "Nome", "Fundo Único de Previdência Social do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
    "Militares", "UENF - Universidade Estadual do Norte Fluminense Darcy Ribeiro", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__10 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__13 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__16 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__17 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__18 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__19 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__20 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__21 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Plano", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", 
    NA, "Plano", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", "Financeiro"
    ), X__22 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__23 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__24 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__25 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Referência", "PAT-SEG", 
    "SEG", "PAT-SEG", "SEG", NA, "Referência", "PAT-SEG", "SEG", 
    "PAT-SEG", "SEG"), X__26 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__27 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), X__28 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__29 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__30 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__31 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__32 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Remun. Bruta", "68881.39", "68881.39", "37259.550000000003", 
    "37259.550000000003", NA, "Data", "42089", "42094", "42090", 
    "42095"), X__33 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__34 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__35 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__36 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Valor Original", "14727.4", "7363.7", "8197.9599999999991", 
    "4098.9799999999996"), X__37 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), X__38 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Base de Cálculo", "61355.47", "61355.47", 
    "33024.04", "33024.04", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__39 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__40 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__41 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Dedução de Benefícios", NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), X__42 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__43 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Servidores", NA, "7", NA, "5", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), X__44 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_), X__45 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__46 = c(NA, 
    "Tipo", "Unidade Gestora", "Militares", "Administração Indireta (Autarquias e Fundações)", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__47 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__48 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Valores Compensados", NA, NA, NA, NA), X__49 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), X__50 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Aposentados", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__51 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    X__52 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Acréscimos Legais", NA, NA, NA, NA), X__53 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Pensionistas", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), X__54 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__55 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Total com Acréscimos", "14727.4", 
    "7363.7", "8197.9599999999991", "4098.9799999999996"), X__56 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Dependentes", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), X__57 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__58 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    X__59 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_)), .Names = c("X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", 
"X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", "X__9", "X__10", "X__11", "X__12", 
"X__13", "X__14", "X__15", "X__16", "X__17", "X__18", "X__19", 
"X__20", "X__21", "X__22", "X__23", "X__24", "X__25", "X__26", 
"X__27", "X__28", "X__29", "X__30", "X__31", "X__32", "X__33", 
"X__34", "X__35", "X__36", "X__37", "X__38", "X__39", "X__40", 
"X__41", "X__42", "X__43", "X__44", "X__45", "X__46", "X__47", 
"X__48", "X__49", "X__50", "X__51", "X__52", "X__53", "X__54", 
"X__55", "X__56", "X__57", "X__58", "X__59"), row.names = c(NA, 
-17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Cada X_n seria uma coluna? Você quer criar uma outra coluna para identificar em qual etapa cada linha pertence é isso?

Comment: Exato Fernandes, cada X-n é uma coluna diferente e eu quero criar uma nova indicado a qual etapa pertence os dados abaixo, assim eu posso aplicar um subset e trabalha com cada base de dados separada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fEtapas <- function(x) {
  linha <- c(grep('\\(ETAPA [0-9]*)$', x[,1]), nrow(x))
  etapa <- rep(NA, nrow(x))
  for(i in 1:(length(linha)-1)) i -> etapa[linha[i]:linha[i+1]]
  x$etapa <- etapa
  return(x)
}

planilha <- fEtapas(planilha.original)

> planilha[c(1:2,59:60)]
                                                   X__1 X__2 X__59 etapa
1             1.2. DADOS DOS ÓRGÃOS/ENTIDADES (ETAPA 1)   NA  <NA>     1
2                                                  CNPJ   NA  <NA>     1
3                                    03.066.219/0001-81   NA  <NA>     1
4                                    03.066.219/0001-81   NA  <NA>     1
5                                    04.809.688/0001-06   NA  <NA>     1
6                     2. BASES E REMUNERAÇÕES (ETAPA 2)   NA  <NA>     2
7                                           Competência   NA  <NA>     2
8                                                 Março   NA  <NA>     2
9                                                 Março   NA  <NA>     2
10                                                Março   NA  <NA>     2
11                                                Março   NA  <NA>     2
12 3. CONTRIBUIÇÕES, APORTES E OUTROS VALORES (ETAPA 3)   NA  <NA>     3
13                                          Competência   NA  <NA>     3
14                                                Março   NA  <NA>     3
15                                                Março   NA  <NA>     3
16                                                Março   NA  <NA>     3
17                                                Março   NA  <NA>     3
```

Funcionará com qualquer número de etapas, assumindo que as etapas estejam em sequência e que sempre sejam identificadas com o mesmo padrão ("(ETAPA XX)" no final da linha). Colocar o código dentro de uma função permite aplicar em qualquer data.frame sem precisar copiar e colar.

Answer (score 1):

A última coluna do dataframe é a de etapas.

```
dados =  structure(list(X__1 = c("1.2. DADOS DOS ÓRGÃOS/ENTIDADES (ETAPA 1)", 
    "CNPJ", "03.066.219/0001-81", "03.066.219/0001-81", "04.809.688/0001-06", 
    "2. BASES E REMUNERAÇÕES (ETAPA 2)", "Competência", "Março", 
    "Março", "Março", "Março", "3. CONTRIBUIÇÕES, APORTES E OUTROS VALORES (ETAPA 3)", 
    "Competência", "Março", "Março", "Março", "Março"), X__2 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), X__3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), X__4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Órgão/Entidade", "AGENERSA - Agência Reguladora de Energia e Saneamento Básico do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
    "AGENERSA - Agência Reguladora de Energia e Saneamento Básico do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
    "AGETRANSP - Agência Reguladora de Serv.Público de Transportes do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
    "AGETRANSP - Agência Reguladora de Serv.Público de Transportes do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
    NA, "Órgão/Entidade", "AGENERSA - Agência Reguladora de Energia e Saneamento Básico do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
    "AGENERSA - Agência Reguladora de Energia e Saneamento Básico do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
    "AGETRANSP - Agência Reguladora de Serv.Público de Transportes do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
    "AGETRANSP - Agência Reguladora de Serv.Público de Transportes do Estado do Rio de Janeiro"
    ), X__6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), X__7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
        X__8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__9 = c(NA, "Nome", "Fundo Único de Previdência Social do Estado do Rio de Janeiro", 
        "Militares", "UENF - Universidade Estadual do Norte Fluminense Darcy Ribeiro", 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__10 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__13 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__16 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__17 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__18 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__19 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__20 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__21 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        "Plano", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", 
        NA, "Plano", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", "Financeiro", "Financeiro"
        ), X__22 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__23 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__24 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__25 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Referência", "PAT-SEG", 
        "SEG", "PAT-SEG", "SEG", NA, "Referência", "PAT-SEG", "SEG", 
        "PAT-SEG", "SEG"), X__26 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__27 = c(NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
        ), X__28 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__29 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__30 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__31 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__32 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        "Remun. Bruta", "68881.39", "68881.39", "37259.550000000003", 
        "37259.550000000003", NA, "Data", "42089", "42094", "42090", 
        "42095"), X__33 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__34 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__35 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__36 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, "Valor Original", "14727.4", "7363.7", "8197.9599999999991", 
        "4098.9799999999996"), X__37 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), X__38 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Base de Cálculo", "61355.47", "61355.47", 
        "33024.04", "33024.04", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__39 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__40 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__41 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Dedução de Benefícios", NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), X__42 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__43 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, "Servidores", NA, "7", NA, "5", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
        ), X__44 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_), X__45 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__46 = c(NA, 
        "Tipo", "Unidade Gestora", "Militares", "Administração Indireta (Autarquias e Fundações)", 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__47 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__48 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, "Valores Compensados", NA, NA, NA, NA), X__49 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA), X__50 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Aposentados", NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__51 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        X__52 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        "Acréscimos Legais", NA, NA, NA, NA), X__53 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, "Pensionistas", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA), X__54 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__55 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Total com Acréscimos", "14727.4", 
        "7363.7", "8197.9599999999991", "4098.9799999999996"), X__56 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Dependentes", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA), X__57 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X__58 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
        NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        X__59 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
        NA_character_)), .Names = c("X__1", "X__2", "X__3", "X__4", 
    "X__5", "X__6", "X__7", "X__8", "X__9", "X__10", "X__11", "X__12", 
    "X__13", "X__14", "X__15", "X__16", "X__17", "X__18", "X__19", 
    "X__20", "X__21", "X__22", "X__23", "X__24", "X__25", "X__26", 
    "X__27", "X__28", "X__29", "X__30", "X__31", "X__32", "X__33", 
    "X__34", "X__35", "X__36", "X__37", "X__38", "X__39", "X__40", 
    "X__41", "X__42", "X__43", "X__44", "X__45", "X__46", "X__47", 
    "X__48", "X__49", "X__50", "X__51", "X__52", "X__53", "X__54", 
    "X__55", "X__56", "X__57", "X__58", "X__59"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

x = dados$X__1 == "1.2. DADOS DOS ÓRGÃOS/ENTIDADES (ETAPA 1)"
y = dados$X__1 == "2. BASES E REMUNERAÇÕES (ETAPA 2)"
z = dados$X__1 == "3. CONTRIBUIÇÕES, APORTES E OUTROS VALORES (ETAPA 3)"

t = nrow(dados)
n = rep(1:t)

dados$etapa = c(rep('Etapa 1',n[y]-n[x]), rep('Etapa 2',n[z]-n[y]), rep('Etapa 3',(t-n[z])+1))
```

Comment: Acabei não informando no problema e farei um edit. Essa base é uma amostra da original. As etapas não possuem necessariamente o mesmo número de linhas. E como irei fazer a mesma análise mensalmente com arquivos diferentes gostaria de automatizar

Comment: Terá mais alguma etapa ou somente essas três? Outra coisa, o nome de cada etapa será o mesmo ou se modicará?

Comment: São mais etapas (5 no total) e a príncipio o nome de cada etapa é o mesmo!

Comment: Editei o script, só acrescentar as outras duas etapas.